# How to output debug info with the dropwizard-migrations liquibase module?

Tags: liquibase, dropwizard

When you run liquibase on the command line, you can set the log level to debug with a command line option:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
  --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
  --classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \
  --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
  --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle" \
  --username=scott \
  --password=tiger \
  --logLevel=debug
  update
```

Does anyone know how to set the log level when running liquibase via the dropwizard-migrations module?

```
java -jar /mydropwizardapp.jar db migrate config.yml
```

(I am having a problem where it intermittently fails to get a lock (*Waiting for changelog lock....*) and my deployment fails, and I'd like to see more detail on what it is doing. I'm pretty sure the lock is not left from a previously failed deployment)

Thanks

Comment: You can check if there is a lock from a previous deployment by running the SQL "SELECT * FROM databasechangeloglock;" on the target DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the logging level to DEBUG on the YAML file:

```
logging:
    level: DEBUG
```

Comment: oops, it didn't occur to me to try to understand the standard drop wizard logging config. thanks!